# Stylesheet com cookie funciona só na segunda vez

Tags: php, css, cookies

Tenho um site que o style é definido pelo cookie "padrao" ou "escuro"

Porém, se você entra a primeira vez nele ele grava o cookie com valor "padrao", mas, não assume o style.

Ele só funciona quando dá um reload na página.

Na primeira linha da página header.php tem:

```
<?php require('/style/css_cookie_check.php'); ?>
```

na parte do stylesheet:

```
<link id="style_cor" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style/<?php echo $estilo_cor; ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Na página "css_cookie_check.php":

```
<?php
    global $estilo_cor;
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['cor_estilo'])) {
        $estilo_cor = setcookie('cor_estilo', 'padrao', (time() + (2 * 3600)));
    } else {
        $estilo_cor = $_COOKIE['cor_estilo'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta linha sua tem um problema:

```
$estilo_cor = setcookie('cor_estilo', 'padrao', (time() + (2 * 3600)));
```

Ela não vai pegar o valor do *cookie* setado, apenas um `true` ou `false`.

Veja uma solução que atribui valor à variável para a página atual e para o cookie:

```
<?php
    global $estilo_cor;
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['cor_estilo'] ) ) {
        $estilo_cor = $_COOKIE['cor_estilo'];
    } else {
        $estilo_cor = 'padrao';
        setcookie( 'cor_estilo', $estilo_cor, ( time() + ( 2 * 3600 ) ) );
    }
?>
```

Se o cookie estiver setado, usamos seu valor. Senão, define `$estilo_cor` e cria um *cookie* com o que foi definido.

A propósito, seria legal definir um padrão pro nome das coisas, você está usando `$estilo_cor`, e `'cor_estilo'`. Pode até funcionar, mas só gera confusão manter um código assim (já basta o PHP, que é todo inconsistente).

### Tirando o global:

Na verdade, nesse caso é até perigoso fazer desta forma, pois cria a ilusão que dá pra chamar a função em outras partes do código, o que não é verdade por se tratar de um *cookie*, mas fica como exemplo de como usar algo de outro source sem `global`:

css_cookie_check.php

```
<?php
    function getStyle() {
       if( isset( $_COOKIE['cor_estilo'] ) ) {
           $estilo_cor = $_COOKIE['cor_estilo'];
       } else {
           $estilo_cor = 'padrao';
           setcookie( 'cor_estilo', $estilo_cor, ( time() + ( 2 * 3600 ) ) );
       }
       return $estilo_cor;
   }
?>
```

E no PHP principal:

```
<?php
   require('/style/css_cookie_check.php');
   $estilo_cor = getStyle();
?>
```

Na verdade, no seu caso, não precisaria nem do meu exemplo e nem do `global`, mas deixei pra ilustrar.

Comment: Cookies não podem ser usados exatamente no mesmo momento que são criados. Eles só assumem depois que a página é recarregada. Isso é padrão. Essa dica do @Bacco deveria resolver, porque quando não existe, além de setar o cookie, ele já define na variável o valor padrão (que poderá ser utilizado no primeiro acesso).

Comment: Clayderson Ferreira, não sabia disto do cookie. Valeu man

Comment: Demais cara, valeu!!!

Comment: Esse negócio de escopo em PHP é meio chato. Eu evito ao máximo usar `global`. Global me lembra escopo de variável de ASP clássico, dá calafrios.