# Grava dois cookies, um para a raiz e um para uma subpágina

Tags: php, css, cookies

Estou querendo usar cookie no meu site para mudar de estilo, mas, tenho conflitos, fiz a pergunta neste link:

[Stylesheet com cookie funciona só na segunda vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117607/stylesheet-com-cookie-funciona-s%C3%B3-na-segunda-vez)

A solução de o Bacco apresentou funcionou, mas percebi que acontece outro problema.

Se estou na página "home" e mudo de estilo, este novo estilo é usado nas outras páginas.
Mas, se estou numa outra página e mudo de estilo, se voltar para a home, ainda está associado ainda o estilo antigo.

Abri o firebug, na aba de cookie

E percebi que ele grava um cookie para a raiz: /site/ de valor "estilo 1".
E grava outro cookie para as subpáginas que acesso: /site/pagina1/ de valor "estilo 2".

Alguém sabe explicar o porquê? e como resolver?

Comment: Tentou definir o caminho do cookie como `'/'` ? veja a sintaxe: `setcookie( 'nome', 'valor', expiracao, 'caminho', 'dominio' );` - E pra testar, tem que deletar todos os _cookies_ do teste, pode ter coisa de teste velho ativada somente em subpasta. No caso do seu teste: `setcookie( 'cor_estilo', $estilo_cor, time() + 2 * 3600, '/' );` - Aproveite e troque o nome do _cookie_, assim evita dúvidas.

Comment: Troquei por "estilo_cor_variavel" e "estilo_cor_cookie". Melhorou?

Comment: o importante de mudar é não confundir com cookies velhos